# <a> Tag inside PHP

Tags: php, html

I used  tag inside php tag. When I run the code it appears as a link. But its not work as a link.It's mean that link is not clickable.

```
$data1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM image_upload INNER JOIN user_table
 ON image_upload.user_id=user_table.user_id WHERE flag=1 ORDER BY timestamp DESC;") 
 or die(mysql_error());

//Puts it into an array

     while($info = mysql_fetch_array($data1)){
     //Outputs the image and other data 
      echo
'<div class="test" id='.$info['ID'].'>';
echo'<div class="username"><a href="profile.php" class="but but_t"      title="">'.$info['user_name'].'</a></div>';

  echo'<div class="imagedisplay"><img src="uploads/'.$info['image'].'" width="230px"     height=auto border="1px solid #"
-webkit-border-radius=" 20px"
-moz-border-radius= "20px"
border-radius="20px"  
  ></div>';
    echo'</div>';
    }
   ?>
```

my css code is

```
    div.test{
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    border-radius:8px;
    height: auto;
    width:250px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#ffffff;
```

}

Can any one help me.

Comment: You don't close your `<a>` tag

Comment: close the link: `'.$info['user_name'].'</a>`

Comment: I closed that tag in my code. It's not work

Comment: There are syntax error too at line #9, line #11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have forgot to close  tag on line #11

CODE

```
$data1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM image_upload INNER JOIN user_table
ON image_upload.user_id=user_table.user_id  WHERE flag=1 ORDER BY timestamp DESC; ")     or die(mysql_error());


//Puts it into an array

 while($info = mysql_fetch_array($data1)){
 //Outputs the image and other data 


echo '<div class="test" id='.$info['ID'].'>';
echo '<div class="username"><a href="profile.php" class="button" title="">'.$info['user_name'].'</a></div>';
echo '<div class="imagedisplay"><img src="uploads/'.$info['image'].'" style="width:230px; height:auto; border:1px solid #000; border-radius:20px;"></div>';
echo '</div>';

}
?>
```

Comment: @Lanka I have updated my answer. There was syntax error at line #11

Comment: your answer works. But I added this link inside another div. Again its not work. I edited my problem.

Comment: @Lanka Show your new code then I will update my answer.

Comment: Yes it works. But still there is a problem. it is with css. In my css test div has float:left attribute. After I use semicolon that css things not work.

Answer (score 0):

try following

while($info = mysql_fetch_array($data1)){

```
echo " <div class=\"username\"><a href=\"profile.php\" class=\"button\" title=\"\">".$info['user_name']."</div>";
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It is probably due to the arrangement of your quotes. Try this clean version:

```
<?php
    echo "<div class='username'>";
    echo "<a href='profile.php' class='button' title=''>$info['user_name']</a>";
    echo "</div>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
echo '<div class="username"><a href="profile.php" class="button" title="" target="_blank">'.$info['user_name'].'</a></div>';
```

Try this...

Answer (score 0):

Link should be close properly

```
'<div class="username">'.'<a href="profile.php" class="button" title="">'.$info['user_name'].'</a></div>'.
```